# After seting up .htaccess redirect server shows to meany redirects and inproper url?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Hi all I have set up simple .htaccess redirect.At first it worked fine,but now it redirects to many times to invalid url(not the one I stated).
First I did:

```
# redirect 
Redirect 301 / http://astangastudio.dk/index2.html
```

It worked fine and than gave me url http://astangastudio.dk/index2.htmlindex2.htmlindex2.html...  , sio I did this redirect:

```
Redirect 301 /index.html new/html/index2.html
```

but it whant except it and stil redirects to index2.htmlindex2.html...

Comment: what are you trying to acheive? do you want to redirect to `new/html/index2.html` when the request is for `index.html`? can you post your `.htaccess` redirect rules here?

Comment: yup.permanent redirect,but for some reason now it all works fine again,nobady did nothing...here is the code:
Redirect 301 /index.html http://astangastudio.dk/new/html/index2.html
I'm just afraid it will start misbehaving again,so waithing for somebody to sugest something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the Redirect pattern **/** also matches the destination path **/index2.html** and redirects **/index2.html** back to **/index2.html** thus you get the **Too many redirect error** .

You need to use RedirectMatch instead of Redirect to avoid this behaviour

```
RedirectMatch ^/$ http://example.com/index2.html
```